# Auto-load a chunk in entry point

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, webpack-splitchunks

Webpack configuration is a part of Vue CLI setup (can be checked with `vue inspect`). This is a relevant part of it:

```
  entry: {
    foo: [
      '.../src/foo.js'
    ],
    barWidget: [
      '.../src/barWidget.js'
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          name: 'chunk-vendors',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          chunks: 'initial'
        },
        common: {
          name: 'chunk-common',
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          chunks: 'initial',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

And HTML output is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/chunk-vendors.[HASH].js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/foo.[HASH].js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/chunk-vendors.[HASH].js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/barWidget.[HASH].js"></script>
```

There's no problem for `foo` to have as many script tags as needed, but `barWidget` is widget entry point that is supposed to be loaded at once with no initial chunk dependencies. My intention is to make `barWidget` be loaded with a single line of code (hash will likely be disabled for this purpose):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/barWidget.js"></script>
```

But in its current state it fails to load if `chunk-vendors` is omitted.

I'd prefer to keep `vendors` and `common` chunks as they are because they are splitted in a reasonable way and can be reused on client side between entry points, but I need `barWidget` to auto-load a chunk it depends on. A less preferable way would be to disable chunks but for `barWidget` only, chunk splitting in other entry points should remain unchanged.

A way to reproduce it is basically a new Vue CLI project with 2 entry points added, or any Webpack project with similarly configured splitting.

Here is [the project](https://anonymous.4open.science/repository/82aa0c68-e9bf-4515-8a4d-0ac05c346b2b/) (listed for completeness):

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

*vue.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    foo: {
      entry: 'src/foo.js',
      template: 'public/foo.html',
      filename: 'foo.html'
    },
    barWidget: {
      entry: 'src/barWidget.js',
      template: 'public/barWidget.html',
      filename: 'barWidget.html'
    },
  },
};
```

*public/foo.html*

*public/barWidget.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*src/foo.js*

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Foo from './Foo.vue'

createApp(Foo).mount('#app')
```

*Foo.vue*

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld msg="Foo"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

*src/barWidget.js*

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import BarWidget from './BarWidget.vue'

createApp(BarWidget).mount('#app')
```

*BarWidget.vue*

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld msg="Bar widget"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

- Can `barWidget` be forced to automatically load `chunk-vendors.[HASH].js` by means of Webpack, without loading it explicitly in the place where `barWidget.[HASH].js` is being used?
- Can `barWidget` entry point be forced to not use other initial chunks (`chunk-vendors`, etc) and output self-sufficient `barWidget.js` bundle, without affecting the way splitting works in other entry points?
- Are there other options for the described scenario?

Comment: If `barWidget ` depends on `node_modules` there's obviously no way considering a `vendor` cache group defined. Generally it's hard to say anything without minimal reproducible test case

Comment: @Andrey Yes, the reason vendor chunk appears is that node_modules is being used, this would be true for virtually any app. I believe the thing that the thing that the question describes is natural to Webpack and can be reproduced with any setup that has initial chunks. But I'll try to add an example that shows this.

Comment: For the `barWidget ` entry, if `barWidget.js ` imports anything from `node_modules `, then vendor chunk will be created. Or if some other code is including something from `node_modules` (i.e. something from webpack config). It's likely that "vendor" chunk won't be created if nothing needs it for the entry, but it looks like that's not the case, so you need to find why code from `node_modules` is needed for the `barWidget`  entry

Comment: maybe specifying a different chunk name on the barWidget imports with the comments annotations would help. see https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

Comment: @Andrey Yes, it imports something from node_modules, this is the case for >99% modular web projects. In this case it's Vue project and it imports at least `vue` itself. To make it clear, the reason why vendor chunk is produced is obvious (same for other possible initial chunks), the question is how to make it unnecessary to explicitly load chunk-vendors.js with `<script>` or else where a specific bundle is being used. I provided a project for completeness, it's currently based on Vue CLI setup with described Webpack config under the hood.

Comment: @TiagoCoelho This is the first thing I've checked but as I far as I can see, annotations are applicable only to dynamic imports, while these chunks are produced from static `import`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want is what is described in this [webpack issue reply](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6717#issuecomment-391999529)

the reply uses a function to exclude the dependencies of a specific entrypoint from being included in a chunk:

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            // ... your current config, just change the chunks property            

            // Exclude pre-main dependencies going into vendors, as doing so
            // will result in webpack only loading pre-main once vendors loaded.
            // But pre-main is the one loading vendors.
            // Currently undocument feature:  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/6791
            chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== "barWidget"
          }
      }
    }
  },
```

to do this with vue should be just a matter of changing the webpack config in the vue.config.js file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
     config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.vendors.chunks = 
       chunk => chunk.name !== "barWidget";
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this but I think it should work as is or with some minimal tweaks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the part from `configureWebpack` is workable and concise. Another answer contains the other part of the puzzle, which is `chunks: ['barWidget']`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function to filter the chunks. See this [Webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6717)

`vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    foo: {
      entry: 'src/foo.js',
      template: 'public/foo.html',
      filename: 'foo.html'
    },
    barWidget: {
      entry: 'src/barWidget.js',
      template: 'public/barWidget.html',
      filename: 'barWidget.html',
      chunks: ['barWidget']
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
      config.optimization.splitChunks({
        cacheGroups: {
          defaultVendors: {
            name: `chunk-vendors`,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10,
            chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== "barWidget"
          },
          common: {
            name: `chunk-common`,
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            chunks: 'initial',
            reuseExistingChunk: true
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `pages.barWidget.chunks` - it is needed because otherwise HtmlWebpackPlugin includes vendors chunk into `barWidget.html` even it is not needed at all...

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: I appreciate the point regarding HtmlWebpackPlugin, saved me some time on debugging.