# Webpack Chunks split for website and widget (based on entrypoint)

Tags: webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I have two webpack entrypoints:
index and widget.

The index entrypoint generates the necessary entry for our main webpage.
The widget entrypoint generates a stripped down version without footer and header, so it can be integrated via an iFrame.
But additionaly to an html integration I would like to provide an window.myLibrary.render function.
In order to integrate this I need a fixed js bundle.

So entry `index` should be like:
`index.bundle.js`
`/js/chunk-common.45abbf61.js`
`/js/chunk-vendors.575dd2e2.js`

And entry `widget` should integrate common and vendors chunk in
`widget.bundle.js`
or load the common and vendor chunk from widget.bundle.js

Is this feasible?

My current configuration looks likes following but it just bundles common and vendor into the entrypoint bundles.

```
optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 2,
        minSize: 20000,
        maxAsyncRequests: 30,
        maxInitialRequests: 30,
        enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
          common: false,
          // We want all vendor (node_modules) to go into a chunk.
          vendors: {
            test(module, chunks) {
              // The (production) vendors bundle only includes modules that are
              // referenced from the main chunk.
              // Modules under node_modules that are referenced from the test bundle should not
              // be included (they are bundled into the test bundle).
              const isInChunk = chunkName =>
                chunks.some(chunk => chunk.name === chunkName);
              console.log(chunks.map(chunk => chunk.name));
              return (
                /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/.test(module.resource) &&
                !isInChunk('widget')
              );
            },
            name: 'vendors',
            // 'all' is confusing - it basically means test all modules regardless if they
            // are statically (via require(x)/import 'x'; ie 'initial' option)
            // or dynamically (via import('x'); ie 'async' option)
            // loaded.
            chunks: 'all',
            reuseExistingChunk: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [Auto-load a chunk in entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924519/auto-load-a-chunk-in-entry-point).

You have to define `chunks: ['widget']` on the widget entrypoint and then define the optimization config as follows:

```
config.optimization.splitChunks({
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          name: `chunk-vendors`,
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          chunks: chunk => chunk.name !== 'widget'
        },
        common: {
          name: `chunk-common`,
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          chunks: 'initial',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    });
```